# Controlar o dado que o MySQL envia para o NodeJS

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js, stored-procedures

Desenvolvi uma storage procedure que "clona" uma proposta e seus produtos, além de fazer alguns updates, mas o retorno que esse procedimento retorna para o meu NodeJS não me é muito útil.

É possível informar/controlar o que o MySQL (Procedure no caso) deve enviar como resposta para o meu back-end para que eu possa enviar essa mesma resposta para o Front-end.

PROCEDURE (ainda em fase de finalização!):

Gostaria de enviar o valor do último ID inserido (LAST_INSERT_ID) para o NodeJS!

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS clone_quote_and_products;

delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE clone_quote_and_products(IN quoteID INT, IN editedClone TINYINT(1))

BEGIN

    IF (editedClone = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO quotes (
            CreatedBy,
         QuoteType,
         AccountName,
         AccountOwner,
         AccountContactName,
         AccountNumber,
         PriceIncrease,
         InitialTerm,
         RenewalTerm,
         FreeMonths,
         EffectiveDate,
         CageUniqueSpaceID,
         URLIdOpportunity,
         IBX,
         QuoteStatus,
         HasTerm,
         NonStandardTerm,
         FreeMonthsORRamp,
         RampMonths,
         RampStartDate,
         RampEndDate,
         RampPerCent,
         Notes,
         MRR,
         NRR
      ) SELECT
         CreatedBy,
         QuoteType,
         AccountName,
         AccountOwner,
         AccountContactName,
         AccountNumber,
         PriceIncrease,
         InitialTerm,
         RenewalTerm,
         FreeMonths,
         EffectiveDate,
         CageUniqueSpaceID,
         URLIdOpportunity,
         IBX,
         QuoteStatus,
         HasTerm,
         NonStandardTerm,
         FreeMonthsORRamp,
         RampMonths,
         RampStartDate,
         RampEndDate,
         RampPerCent,
         Notes,
         MRR,
         NRR  
        FROM quotes
        WHERE quotes.id = quoteID;
   END IF;

   UPDATE quotes AS Q
   SET Q.Version = CONCAT('[{"ID":', (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()), ', "Version": 1}]')
   WHERE Q.id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

END //
delimiter ;

# CALL clone_quote_and_products(802, 0);
```

NodeJS:

```
function Quote_CloneDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

// Retrieve Cloned Quote
Quote_CloneDAO.prototype.cloneQuoteAndProducts = function (id, editedQuote, callback) {
    this._connection.query(`
        CALL clone_quote_and_products(?, ?);
    `, [id, editedQuote], callback)
}

module.exports = () => {
    return Quote_CloneDAO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira alteração que será necessário é a de declarar um parâmetro do tipo `OUT` na sua `PROCEDURE`:

```
-- ...
CREATE PROCEDURE clone_quote_and_products(IN quoteID INT,
                                          IN editedClone TINYINT(1),
                                          OUT id INT)
-- ...
```

Dentro da `PROCEDURE` atribua o valor à variável:

```
-- ...
SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- ...
```

Na criação da sua conexão, envie o atributo `multipleStatements` com o valor `true`, mais ou menos como no exemplo abaixo:

```
// ...
const connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
// ...
```

E na sua `query` envie a variável e logo em seguida realize um `SELECT` para obter o retorno da mesma, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
// ...
this._connection.query('CALL clone_quote_and_products(?, ?, @id); SELECT @id', [id, editedQuote], callback);
// ...
```

Comment: Funcionou conforme a minha necessidade, obrigado!